# $T=-T^{*}$, show that $T+\alpha I$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, determinant

Please don't answer the question. Just tell me if I am in the right direction. I should be able to solve this.

We are given $T=-T^{*}$, show that $T+\alpha I$ is invertibe for all real alphas that aren't zero.

What I did:

$det(T+\alpha I) = det(-T^{*}+\alpha I)=det(-\bar T+\alpha I) = \overline {det(-T+\alpha I)}$

And here I'm pretty much stuck. Am I in the right direction?

Comment: How did you come up with the determinant is real? After all, $\;T+\alpha I\neq -T+\alpha I\;$ ...

Comment: wait wait my bad. corrected the mistake.

Comment: Show that if $T=-T^*$, then all eigenvalues are purely imaginary. You don't need to use the determinant for this.

Comment: That is a very good idea actually. Write it as answer and i'll accept it for your bonus points :)

Comment: There is a shorter way to show it using just one matrix multiplication. And some reasoning on what matrices are clearly positive definite.

Comment: @ Oria Gruber:  By $T^*$ you mean the Hermitian adjoint of $T$, right?  What is often weritten $T^\dagger$?

Comment: well since we don't know if $T$ is complex or real, $T^{*}$ is defined as such: $T^{*}$ is the matrix such that for any vector $u$: $<Tu,u> = <u,T^{*}u>$

Comment: @Oria Gruber:  OK, so is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ a Euclidean or Hermitian inner product?  Or do we need to handle both cases.  It's all good, neverthless . . ., so +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $T=-T^*$, we have for any $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ that $\mathrm{Re}(x^*Tx)=0$. Assume that $\alpha I+T$ (with real $\alpha\neq 0$) is singular, that is, there exists a nonzero $y\in\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $(\alpha I + T)y=0$ and hence $\alpha y=-Ty$. Multiplying with $y^*$ gives $\alpha y^*y=-y^*Ty$. We get a contradiction, since $\alpha y^*y$ is real and nonzero, while $\mathrm{Re}(y^*Ty)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

copper.hat's comment was on point, in my book.

As long as $T^*$ is such that $\langle Tu, v \rangle = \langle u, T^*v \rangle$ (see Oria Gruber's remarks in the comments), we have that $\langle x, Tx \rangle$ is purely imaginary for all vectors $x$, since

$\langle x, Tx \rangle^* = \langle Tx, x \rangle = \langle x, T^*x \rangle = -\langle x, Tx \rangle, \tag{1}$

where the raised $*$ means complex conjugation when applied to numbers, as in $\langle x, Tx \rangle^*$ which occurs at the left of equation (1), and the operation ${} ^*$ which takes $T \to T^*$ when applied to operators such as $T$.  In any event, this means the eigenvalues of $T$ are purely imaginary, since if we have

$Tv = \lambda v \tag{2}$

with $\Vert v \Vert = \langle v, v \rangle^{1/2}= 1$, then

$\lambda = \lambda \Vert v \Vert = \lambda \langle v, v \rangle = \langle v, \lambda v \rangle = \langle v, Tv \rangle. \tag{3}$

We now use the salutory fact that, for any scalar $\alpha$,

$Tv = \lambda v \Leftrightarrow (T + \alpha I)v = (\lambda + \alpha)v; \tag{4}$

since as we have seen the eigenvalues of $T$ are purely imaginary, by (4) those of $T + \alpha I$ for real $\alpha \ne 0$ all have non-vanishing real part; hence none can be zero; hence $T + \alpha I$ is nonsingular and and so invertible.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Best Wishes for the New Year,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***